# List of Python functions, in their order of definition in the module

Tags: python, doctest

For a test-driven pedagogical module, I need to check doctests in a precise order.
Is there a way to grab all callables in the current module, in their order of definition?

What I tried:

- Loop on globals and check if the object is a callable. The problem is that globals is a dict and thus not ordered.
- Using the doctests directly is not convenient because the "stop at first error" won't work for me as I have several functions to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Martijn, I eventually found.
This is a complete snippet for Python3.

```
import sys
import inspect

def f1():
    "f1!"
    pass
def f3():
    "f3!"
    pass
def f2():
    "f2!"
    pass

funcs = [elt[1] for elt in inspect.getmembers(sys.modules[__name__],
                                              inspect.isfunction)]
ordered_funcs = sorted(funcs, key=lambda f: f.__code__.co_firstlineno)
for f in ordered_funcs:
    print(f.__doc__)
```

Answer (score 9):

Each function object has a code object which stores the first line number, so you can use:

```
import inspect

ordered = sorted(inspect.getmembers(moduleobj, inspect.isfunction), 
                 key=lambda kv: kv[1].__code__.co_firstlineno)
```

to get a sorted list of `(name, function)` pairs. For Python 2.5 and older, you'll need to use `.func_code` instead of `.__code__`.

You may need to further filter on functions that were defined *in* the module itself and have not been imported; `func.__module__ == moduleobj.__name__` should suffice there.

Comment: Note that this is implementation detail of CPython and it might break in different versions, or other implementations.

Comment: @poke: Indeed, the whole *concept* of code objects is an exposed detail of the CPython interpreter.

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I struggled a bit more because I didn't realise that your answer was Python2 only. In P3, `func_code` was replaced with `__code__`. Also, I needed `sys.modules[__name__]` to grab the current module. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, use `__code__` for Python 3, which incidentally also works for Python 2.6 and 2.7.

Comment: Sorry, you struggled; had you asked I could have corrected this for you immediately. :-)